# Raspberry pi 3b+ robot ,pyPS4Controller syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, syntax-error, raspberry-pi3

```
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller
```

When I run this code I get this Syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPS4Controller/controller.py", line 430
    (*tv_sec, value, button_type, button_id) = struct.unpack(self.event_format, event)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm trying to connect my robot to my ps4 controller, I'm a newbie so please take it easy with the jargon XD

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when I ran it from root using python3 via

```
sudo python3 file.py
```